# Why does my code scrape only scrape the first 3 pictures, not all of them?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to learn how to webscrape with beautifulsoup and followed an online guide to scrape some baby yoda pics of the [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/BabyYoda/). This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request 

headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"}
url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/BabyYoda/"
response=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

pics=soup.find_all("img",attrs = {"alt":"Post image"})

number=0
for image in pics:
    image_src=image["src"]
    print(image_src)
    #urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_src,str(number))
    number+=1
```

Output:

```
https://preview.redd.it/ps7dvuuccm251.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=5ba4ce4c000ea8694e594849a9f4b0c9ed14a7d1
https://preview.redd.it/wztcej6fvi251.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=879664f218e53b62de7a7d390a0bb70b6baa302c
https://preview.redd.it/0dqi2d6s7k251.jpg?width=640&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=5a98bb4431d9c07bfd0912faae6dfb0c15aba058
```

This gives me the first 3 images only. I think the problem lies in the fact the web page constantly updates as you scroll, giving rise to more images. I am not sure if the webpage, that I am downloading as a HTML, contains all this information. Can anyone confirm or see why I dont get all the images?

Answer (score 0):

You can test this by saving the webpage... If only 3 images come that mean your theory is right,That the page loads on scroll..

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful Soup will only extract data on page load. Which you can view by right-click and selecting *View page source*. The URL you've supplied has infinite scrolling (where by additional data is loaded by scrolling down). To get around this you could use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)